# kineticjs and using offset and rotate for a group

Tags: rotation, kineticjs, offset

I have a kineticjs stage. Inside it there is a kinetijs layout and inside the layout some Kineticjsgroups. I want to rotate some the groups but when using offset it won't render groups correctly, but off stage. I am attaching two images to see the result of using offset in a KineticJS group.

[image: normal] and

[image: with offset]

The code I used was the following.

```
myGroup.offset(`{x:myGroup.getWidth() / 2, y: myGroup.getHeight() / 2});
myGroup.rotateDeg(180);
myStage.draw();
```

and I get the result of the secon Image. The group is moved to the left, and up.Does offset works in a different way? Why does the usage of offset displaces the object when it should just change the way it rotates?

Answer (score 0):

> Why does the usage of offset displaces the object when it should just change the way it rotates?

It should not. `offset` is moving object.

Comment: Didn't quite get your answer. So you say its normal when you use offset the object to be moved in a different position?

Comment: Yes. When you use `offset` the object to be moved.

Comment: so in order for an object to be rotated in the center of it and also be placed when you want you need to add offset.x and offset.y on x and y properties.